# Split a list of arrays and save each array in a new variable

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following function that resamples 100 times a file of ~800 elements:

```
def resample(arg_array):
    all_sets = []
    i = 1
    while i <= 100:
        subset = np.random.choice(arg_array, 100, replace=True)
        all_sets.append(subset)
        i += 1
    return all_sets
```

This produces a list of arrays with 100 elements each, stored in `all_sets`.

I need to split this list and save each array into a new variable. Thought about doing list comprehension, but doing `set1, set2, ..., set100 = [list comprehension]` just doesn't seem very efficient or elegant at all.

Would be great if Python had something like bash where you can generate a new variable name for each pass in a loop.

Comment: You could make a class and make each set an attribute of that class using ```setattr()``` But I'd be surprised if you really need to do that rather than just accessing the list elements by their index. Can you expand a bit more on the use case?

Comment: This is basically for a jackknife analysis. Have about 700 (not 800) IDs from which to resample and do my tests against 100 controls. Repeat 100 times. Since my stuff is done on the shell, I would like to pass a command line argument (txt file with the IDs) as the function argument, and then output the new 100-element resampled lists to new txt files that I can work on downstream.

Comment: Unpacking from a list or tuple is the only reasonable python code.  'dynamically' creating variable names is awkward and distinctly un-pythonic.  Use lists and dicts if you need to work with many objects.

Comment: I guess I could do a loop and write each element in the list or dict in a new file, but the globals() solution worked as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about like this?

```
def resample(arg_array):
    for i in range(1, 101):
        subset = np.random.choice(arg_array, 100, replace=True)
        globals()[f"set{i}"] = subset
```

Comment: That worked for what I need. I used that to write each subset into a new file, which is exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a variable for each set you could store them in a dictionary like this.

```
def resample(arg_array):
    sample_map = {}
    for n in range(1, 100+1):
        subset = np.random.choice(arg_array, 100, replace=True)
        sample_map[n] = subset
    return sample_map
```

Or even this

```
def resample(arg_array):
    sample_map = {n:np.random.choice(arg_array, 100, replace=True) for n in range(1, 100+1)}
    return sample_map
```